# add key value pairs to object from an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I automate the process of assigning the **key to an object** from an **array** and the **value** to contain the **same element** as a string?

---

I have an empty object and an array:

`const myObject= {};`

```
const newsCategory = ['business', 'entertainment', 'general', 'health', 'science'];
```

I need to populate the **object** with key-value pairs.

The **key** should be each element from the **newsCategory** array.

The **value** should be an instance of another object.

```
new GetNews({country: 'gb', category: newsCategory[element]});
```

---

I can do this the manual way, assigning each category individually:

```
myObject.business = new GetNews({country: 'gb', category: newsCategory ['business']});
```

...and the same to the rest of the categories.

The result would be

```js
{
    business: GetNews {
                category: "business"
                country: "gb"
                }
    entertainment: GetNews {
                category: "entertainment"
                country: "gb"
                }
    general: GetNews {
                category: "general"
                country: "gb"
                }
    health: GetNews {
                category: "health"
                country: "gb"
                }
    science: GetNews {
                category: "science"
                country: "gb"
                }
    
}
```

---

**I need to do this process automatically, with a loop for example.**

This is my attempt but it's not working.

```js
newsCategory.forEach((category) => {
        let cat = String.raw`${category}`; //to get the raw string
         myObj.cat = new GetNews({country: 'gb', category: category});
    })
};

/*
output: 

{cat: "undefined[object Object][object Object][object Obj…ect][object Object][object Object][object Object]"}
*/
```

---

How can I automate the process of assigning the **key to an object** from an **array** and the **value** to contain the **same element** as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `myObj.cat` you should do `myObj[cat]` so that `cat` is evaluated as the key value, otherwise you're setting a key named `"cat"`.

Also `String.raw` is weird, don't use that. Your categories are strings already.

```
newsCategory.forEach((category) => {
        myObj[category] = new GetNews({country: 'gb', category: category});
    })
};
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake, your solution worked well.